# Caliburn.Micro, multiple ActiveItem from UserControl and Conductor.OneActive

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, caliburn.micro

I have a question but in stat i will describe you what im asking about.

Im making an app with Caliburn.Micro Framework. What i want to do is to make multiple `ActiveItem` (as `UserControl`)  but display one at the same time. Something like:

```
<ContentControl x:Name="ActiveItem_1"/>

<ContentControl x:Name="ActiveItem_2"/>

<ContentControl x:Name="ActiveItem_3"/>

<ContentControl x:Name="ActiveItem_4"/>
```

I choose which `UserControl` to display by `Buttons`

So i want to open only one `UserControl` at the same time (when i open one, second is not allowed to open).

My ViewModel.cs looks like this:

```
using Caliburn.Micro;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace TaskManager.ViewModels
{
    class MainWindowViewModel : Conductor<IScreen>.Collection.OneActive
    {
        public void LoadLoginPage()
        {
            ActivateItem(new LoginViewModel());
        }

        public void LoadTasksPage()
        {
            //And here i have no idea what to do, 
            //how to make another UserControl to be ActiveItem
        }
    }
}
```

So, how to name or code the couple of user controls to be OneActive? I could use one UserControl and changing it size and Margin, but i think it will be more complicated than changing UserControls

Thanks for advices!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand this correctly you want to have 4 content controls but only have one contain a view at any one time. I.E. You press button 1 and content control 1 has a view but then when you click another button content control 1 goes away and the content control for the new button is populated?

You can't use ActivateItem as ActivateItem requires that you have a contentcontrol named ActiveItem.

You would need to do something like this:

```
Button1ViewModel ActiveItem_1 = null;
Button2ViewModel ActiveItem_2 = null;
Button3ViewModel ActiveItem_3 = null;
Button4ViewModel ActiveItem_4 = null;

public void Button1()
{
    if (ActiveItem_1 == null)
        ActiveItem_1 = new Button1ViewModel();

    if (ActiveItem_2 != null)
    {
        ActiveItem_2.TryClose();
        ActiveItem_2 = null;
    }

    if (ActiveItem_3 != null)
    {
        ActiveItem_3.TryClose();
        ActiveItem_3 = null;
    }

    if (ActiveItem_4 != null)
    {
        ActiveItem_4.TryClose()
        ActiveItem4 = null;
    }
}
```

Do a similar thing for the other buttons opening the correct view model for each one and closing the others.

Really you should do OneActive and just have one contentcontrol named ActiveItem and have that populate each time you click one of the buttons. As long as you don't set an explicit size the contentcontrol will resize to your views (or you could design all your views to be the same size).

Comment: It have sense. I will check it in a few days (summer time) and i will give u a feedback, if it work or not. If it wont work, i will work at one user control at once. It will be more elegant (couple UserControls looks easier for me, we dont need to change size or place of one user control)